# Automatically assign parent category to child category url's

Tags: categories, child-categories

I have multiple parent categories:

Kids Stuff
Dining Out
Things to Do

Each of those parents have multiple children:

Kids Stuff -> Schools, Camps, Parties
Dining Out -> Restaurants, Catering
Things to Do -> Day Trips, Weekend Getaways, Activities

Entries can be in more than one Parent as well as more than one Child.

On the individual entry page, I need to show the categories the entry is assigned and the link to the (parent or child) category page.

PARENTS:

/kids-stuff/
/dining-out/
/things-to-do/

Parents work fine.  It's the Children that are a problem.

I want the Child Category URL's to show the Parent name (each parent category has a different template), as well as the child name like so:

CHILDREN: 
/kids-stuff/schools/
/kids-stuff/camps/
/kids-stuff/parties/
/dining-out/restaurants/

and so on.

Instead EE is giving them the following URL's
/schools/
/camps/
/parties/
/restaurants/

Thanks for any help or insight you can offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, the solution here is to use the [GWcode Categories plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories) rather than the standard EE Channel Categories tag, and [Low Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/) instead of relying on EE's dynamic category methods.

So, to output your categories list (as a simple example):

```
{exp:gwcode_categories channel="my_channel"}
    <a href="/filter/{complete_path}">{cat_name}</a>
{exp:gwcode_categories}
```

This will output a nested list of categories, and each will link to a URL containing every `category_url_title` all the way up the category tree for that particular category.

Then, in your **filter/index** template (again, just an example):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" category="{segment_category_ids}"}
    ... list your stuff ...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This will show only entries assigned to *all* of the categories listed in the URL.

Comment: Thanks Derek.  It looks like {complete_path} is what I'm after.  Low Seg2Cat isn't needed as my category templates are displaying just fine the way we have it.  Thank you!